# Beam size to span 18 feet for deck roof

Tags: deck, patio, beam, pergola, cover

I'm looking for help on planning a roof over a deck I plan on adding to my house. The roof will be 18' wide and extend out 12' from the house. I want to have at least a 1' overhang on each side making the roof 12x20.

I plan on using polycarbonate sheets as roofing so it does not need to support much weight. Building in a location that does not experience snow. What size post and beam do I need to use to span the 18' between support posts?

Here is the concept design.

[image: Deck Concept Photo]

Comment: Welcome. I've attempted to simplify your post to remove non-essential information. Feel free to revise further to clarify anything.

Comment: There are folks here willing to do this for you (and they'll probably be along shortly), but here are some things that might help you: https://www.google.com/search?q=beam+load+calculator&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&oq=beam+load+cal&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l6.1990j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Truss span is what you look up.                                 A 2" by 10" 16" on center will work for 20 ft 8 inches. With a 3/12 pitch.  Less than that changes it to 19 ft 9 inches.  If you include a ceiling  of some sort then go 12 inches on center.
The dimensions I noted are found in many places. But the best location is the International Residential Code for rafter size R802.4.1 R802.4.1(1) through R802.4.1(8). This goes through types of wood and a few other variants. Snow loads in northern areas are in the local codes. Usually decreased spacing. But you noted No Snow so not an issue.

Comment: You're saying that the snow load makes no difference to the strength requirements for a roof? Especially a fairly flat (3/12) roof? I'd suggest that you [edit] your answer to include some code references that will support this, as it goes against most information I've seen and common sense.

Comment: Yes I guess I could have been more clear.   In retrospect I should have left the wording out on snow. A 3/12 roof is not suggested for areas with snow although done with trusses designed for the area snow loads. Examples are flat roof commercial buildings. The dimensions I noted are found in many places. But the best location is the International Residential Code for rafter size R802.4.1 R802.4.1(1) through R802.4.1(8).  This goes through types of wood and a few other variants.  Snow loads in northern areas are in the local codes. Usually decreased spacing.

Comment: Please [edit] that info into your answer. It helps with discoverability (not everyone reads comments) and comments are ephemeral - they can get deleted.

Comment: Done.Thanks for the suggestions.